# Rounding to 2 decimals with the math method

Tags: java, math, decimal, rounding

So I'm working on an assignment where I'm supposed to do a table with different values etc. But I have run into a problem where the (charging time/laddningstid(h)) round up to 16.0 when I want it so say 15.57. Since 35.8/2.3 = 15.57.

So my question is what have I done wrong here? How can I make it say the correct value instead of 16.0

CODE:

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    double batteryEffect = 35.8;
    int current = 10;
    int current1 = 16;
    int current2 = 32;

    int voltage = 230;
    int voltage1 = 400;

    
    double calcEffect = 0;

    int noOfDecimals = 2;
    double scale = 0;
    scale = Math.pow(10, noOfDecimals);
    calcEffect = Math.round(current*voltage)*scale/scale/1000;

    
    double calcCharge = 0;

    calcCharge = Math.round(batteryEffect/calcEffect)*scale/scale;
    

    System.out.print("Batteri" + " " + batteryEffect + "(kWh)");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("\nStröm(A)\tSpänning(V)\tLaddeffekt(kW)\tLaddningstid(h)");  
    System.out.print("\n=======================================================");
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print(current + "\t\t\t" + voltage + "\t\t\t"  + calcEffect + "\t\t\t\t" + calcCharge);
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print(current1 + "\t\t\t" + voltage);
  }
}
```

EDIT: My bad I didn't know the picture was gonna get that small first time posting here.

Comment: Without seeing your code it isn't possible to say what you've done wrong.

Comment: nobody can read that.  Post code and data as TEXT please.

Comment: @tgdavies Well I attached a link to a screenshot of the code on the top of the post..

Comment: @OldProgrammer Ok, changed it!

Comment: You are hopefully aware that floating point (double) is just a finite sum of (negative) powers of 2, merely approximating the decimal value like 15.57. In reality you could easily get something like 15.5699999984. `System.out.printf("Two decimals %.2f!%n", 15.57);` would output the number in two decimals. And then there is BigDecimal, a fixed point implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The `Math.round` function rounds its argument to the nearest integer, so it is expected that it rounds 15.57 to 16.

If you want to limit to number of digits after the decimal point, you can use `calcCharge.toFixed(2)` (without the `Math.round`). Or you can do `Math.round(calcCharge * 100) / 100`.